# allow_url_fopen not working in server?

Tags: php, fopen

I am using ups service for my project,I have the following code which is working fine in my localhost,

```
.......
 $fp = fopen($url, "r");    
      while(!feof($fp)){ 
        $result = fgets($fp, 500);
        $result = explode("%", $result);
         //print_obj($result);
        $errcode = substr($result[0], -1);
        switch($errcode){
          case 3:
            $returnval = $result[8];
                break;
          case 4:
            $returnval = $result[8];
            break;
          case 5:
            $returnval = $result[1];
            break;
          case 6:
            $returnval = $result[1];
            break;
        }
      }
      fclose($fp);
.....
```

But `fopen` is not working in my server, i checked ini settings `allow_url_fopen On` has been enabled already. Is there any other settings i missed. Kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some servers, access to distant url ( outgoing traffic on port ) are disabled by network managers, for security reasons. I saw this problem many times before. It may be for this reason.

If it's the reason and you know what url ( and server IP ) you have to request, you can ask for adding some iptables rules to allow access to that URL.

Comment: yes firewall has been blocked, now we have opened access for it. Its working fine now.