# Prestashop allow_url_fopen set to On, still showing error

Tags: php, prestashop, fopen

My Prestashop install is not able to access outside urls, and its really beginning to drive me nuts!
The response in

I've already changed the php.ini setting, in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

which did nothing for it,

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Then, 
I managed to try [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029951/allow-url-fopen-not-working-in-server), which still did not eliminate the error, which basically adds a php.ini file into the root directory with the above setting.

The server is physically located at my residence, and the prestashop install is accessible [here](http://pinkeye.noip.me/breakitfix.it)

I'm most weak in this area, so I'm not able to understand why this is happening. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Did you restart your server so PHP can use new settings from php.ini?

Comment: I did do that. restart the server meaning actually rebooting the server

Answer (score 0):

The typical problem I've had with issues like PHP settings having no effect is usually having multiple php.ini files (sometimes multiple PHP setups from different attempts, as well). Search Your system for multiple php.ini files and verify which one is correct.

Alternatively, Your php.ini file may not be where PHP expects to find it. Run phpinfo() and see what php.ini file Your setup reads (or tries to read).

Thirdly, please verify that You have appropriate permissions set for the php.ini file - the web server process should be able to read this file.